# How to change colour of gridview cells in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have gridview which is displaying data like

```
Name  marks old     marks new    salaryold  salarynew
sasi     55         78            23000      45000
kiran    67         45            35000      20000
peter    23         23            10000      10000
```

What I want is, I want to give different colour if the old value is different than new value,give colour for old value as Green and new value as Red,If no change give Green both. How to do it in `Rowdatabound` or any other event?

Comment: Why are you giving yourself the lowest salary? :(

Comment: @peter have posted a solution for you to try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it (sorry don't have VS on this machine).

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //Proper input validation should be done here. i.e. empty string etc
        var oldSalary =  Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[3].Text);
        var newSalary =  Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[4].Text);

        if(oldSalary == newSalary){
            e.Row.Cells[3].ForeColor = Color.FromName("green");
            e.Row.Cells[4].ForeColor = Color.FromName("green");
        }
        else{
            e.Row.Cells[3].ForeColor = Color.FromName("green");
            e.Row.Cells[4].ForeColor = Color.FromName("red");
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var lblOldSalary = e.Row.FindControl("lblOldSalary") as Label;
        var lblNewSalary = e.Row.FindControl("lblNewSalary") as Label;

        //Proper input validation should be done here. i.e. empty string etc
        var oldSalary =  Convert.ToInt32(lblOldSalary.Text);
        var newSalary =  Convert.ToInt32(lblNewSalary.Text);

        if(oldSalary == newSalary){
            lblOldSalary.ForeColor = Color.FromName("green");
            lblNewSalary.ForeColor = Color.FromName("green");
        }
        else{
            lblOldSalary.ForeColor = Color.FromName("green");
            lblNewSalary.ForeColor = Color.FromName("red");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is fixed for cells 3 and cell4,how to make it generic??

Comment: Change the column in the GridView to be a template field column. i.e. <Asp:Label Id="lblOldSalary"> <asp:Label Id="lblNewSalary"

Comment: Don't you mean `if(oldSalary == newSalary)`?

Comment: @Seany84 grid i showed is a minimal one.It has actually 15 columns contains old and new columns.If that is the case which is the generic solution here?

Comment: @peter I have answered your original question. I think if you have a different one, you should open a new question and mark this as the answer.

Comment: @peter You'll have to assign which columns this applies to. The problem with making this generic is that if you do so, the program will have a hard time figuring out which columns you actually mean. As Seany has stated, this is a whole other problem.